# Should I capitalize the keyword return as Return as MSDN shows changing syntax for C# in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, return

I see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) link. According to the version information, it's valid from VS2015.

```
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
  Return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
}
```

Is *return* statement going to be capitalized in the future?

Comment: more likely it's a typo...

Comment: @KeithHall I don't know... Once, I said that it was a typo when I saw *public int Donkey => 3;* and ever since, I'm very reluctant to jump to the typo-type of conclusions.

Comment: A new version of `VS` doesn't change syntax of code

Comment: if it was supposed to be a keyword, I'm sure it would be syntax highlighted in blue like you see at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx ;)

Comment: @MarkPerera Correct. I was a bit vague. I mean that the new version of VS usually comes with a newer version of the framework and **that** is what I meant. VS itself is just a text editor (as in: the space station is "just" a vehicle, hehe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, its a typo. **Return** is not something that you should try. If you try this on VS(even in newer version) it will give you compile time error.  Here is the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx)

Comment: It's 06:30 in the morning. I saw the capitalized *return* and paniced...

Comment: Yep! VS 2015 update 3 is giving compilation error if you try capitalized `Return` keyword.